# How to hook into a game written in C++

Tags: c++, modding

Okay, so there is a game I want to mod and it is written in C++. And from what I know you can't just decompile and edit the code like Java else it just decompiles into Assembly. So I was wondering how could you actually go about modding a game entirely written in C++ without having to spend hours looking at Assembly instructions. Thanks in advance

Comment: it's not an easy job, if you don't already have lots of programming experience don't even think about it.

Comment: Which game?  Some have more obvious ways to hijack the process than others.  Also realize that cheat-detection systems are often triggered by such mods.

Comment: The game is Cube World it has only just came out and won't have official modding support and I wanted to customize the server so it could have more than 4 players. I have a reasonable amount of programming knowledge too from a variety of languages.

Comment: If you want to mod the server, another possibility is to rewrite the server with your modifications, as long as it maintains the same protocol it will work, though you would have to reverse engineer it and even then more players might require a modification to the protocol as well.

Answer (score 4):

The most common solution is to use a hex editor and decompiled assembly and then poking at various bits of data or code after using the assembly to figure out *which* bits to poke and in which way.

For more complex changes the common "attack" is to hijack a DLL.  For example, if the game loads D3D, you could trick the system into loading a different DLL in its place.  This is non-trivial as you not only must implement your changes but must also whatever DLL you hijacked (which you might do by passing calls through to the "real" DLL, but this is non-trivial).  You can also inject a DLL in place of the application's normal entry point, which is a bit less cumbersome usually but not always.

Even then, all you have done is given yourself the ability to inject code into the game's process.  If you actually want to inject hooks into the code, modify data, etc., you have to find places that such is even possible.  This is going to go back to reading Assembly code and decoding how the game works.  Anything you do is likely to change or break any time the game is updated, of course.

The code to project like [NVSE](http://nvse.silverlock.org/) are online and available.  If in doubt, see what they did for code injection.  Again, actually making the mod you want will require poking around in the guys of the assembly.

For what you're trying to do, it may or may not be simple.  Depending on how the server is written, there may just be a hard-coded limit of 4 during login.  Or the assumption of only 4 players might be made all throughout the code and various data structures.  Increasing the limit might require "only" reading the assembly to find where this limit is imposed to change it with a hex editor, or it might require replacing a large number of non-trivial sections of code which will take you months just to find.

Honestly, your best bet is to just talk to the author of CubeWorld about it.  If it makes sense, maybe they'll increase the limit or make it a config option.  A proper modding API in a future version might even be on the table.

Answer (score 0):

If a game is written in C++ *but* the code is not provided, things get complicated fast.  The easiest way to go about changing the game is usually to attack any resource files.  Some games have folders with .bin or .dat files that are all the resources compressed together.  Hex editors and creative data munging would be the way to go about looking at those.

Comment: There are .dat files and there are also Data Base Files

Comment: I'm not going to split hairs.  Valve maintains no less than 4 proprietary formats, for example.  They aren't terrible hard to figure out but it is still time intensive.

Comment: This is not a Valve game though. Its called Cube World